# Как решить эту задачу с помощью жадного алгоритма (Python)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Рассмотрим шахматную доску с r строками и c столбцами. Найдите наибольшее количество королей, которых можно разместить на доске r×c, с выполнение следующих условий:

1. В любой клетке на доске может находиться не более одного короля.
2. У любого короля есть МИНИМУМ один возможный ход на свободную клетку на доске.

Формат ввода
Единственная строка содержит два целых числа r и c.

Ограничения: 1≤r,c≤100.

Формат вывода
Наибольшее количество королей.

Пример 1
Ввод:
5 1
Вывод:
3

Пример 2
Ввод:
3 3
Вывод:
8

Пример 3
Ввод:
4 4
Вывод:
12

Ограничение памяти
512.0 Мб
Ограничение времени
2 с

Ввод
стандартный ввод или input.txt

Вывод
стандартный вывод или output.txt

Comment: Что-то мне пока кажется навскидку, что это блоки 3х3, с пустой центральной клеткой, ну, а на краях надо смотреть отдельно, что там остается. Две пустых строки - 5 королей с пустышкой, одна - два короля с пустышкой... Ну и отдельно варианты с углом, где сходятся неполные блоки. Нет? Еще раз — это так, с ходу, не думая :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3026006/maximum-number-of-kings-on-the-chessboard-subject-to-some-rules достаточно формулы (`print((m * n) - (ceil(m/3) * ceil(n/3)))`)

Comment: @gord1402 спасибо большое!

Comment: @gord1402 О, моя идея была верной :)